# Dimension of proset - the case of $\Delta_X$ and $X^2$

Tags: order-theory

I juse met the defiition of *dimension of proset* and I found myself stuck on a question (actually I am having various troubles with it, so the one I am asking is only one part of the problem I found).

Assuming that $\Delta_X$ is the **Diagonal Relation** on an arbitrary set $X$:
1) what is $dim(X,\Delta_X)$?
2) what is $dim(X,X^2)$?

1) After quite a lot of thoughts, I think that $dim(X,\Delta_X)=2$. The intuition I had is that we have to imagine two chains, the first that moves from - let's say - $a_1$ to $a_n$, while the other chain moves in the opposite direction and the $a_i$ are the elements on which we define the diagonal relation. If we intersect the two chains, indeed we get the original diagonal relation.

2) About $dim(X,X^2)$, I think that it should be equal 1. My line of reasoning is the following: $dim(X,X^2)$ is already a complete preorder (actually it is - so to speak - the most complete), so there is nothing to extend and there is no intersection to work on.

Are my lines if reasoning ok?
Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen "proset" before (though "Prosit!" is familiar).  I suppose it abbreviates pre-ordered set.  And I imagine the definition of "dimension" is just as in the case of partially ordered sets: The minimum number of linear pre-orders (on the same set) whose intersection is the given pre-order.  If so, then your answers are correct.

Comment: Then "santè" and "nasdrovie" should be familiar as well! Btw, yes, I found couple of times proset as an abbreviation of quasiorder, and yes again, I meant the standard definition of dimension of posets due to Dushnik & Miller. Thus, if you write it as answer, I will be happy to accept it. Thanks a lot!